# Discord api getMessageHistory

Tags: php, discord

Could you explain how to use getMessageHistory() from the php discord library (teamreflex)?
https://github.com/teamreflex/DiscordPHP/blob/master/src/Discord/Parts/Channel/Channel.php#L334
I use:
`$messages = $channel->getMessageHistory(100);`

Comment: place some code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developers for that API say that it's dead.

> Library is currently dead,  doubt it works at all and if it does there are so many bugs.

[Their github](https://github.com/teamreflex/DiscordPHP)

Comment: You think it doesn't work anymore? do you have another library?